# Best way to get path data from a line

Tags: d3.js, svg

In D3 what is the best way to get the SVG Path string from a line that is created by appending a line to the DOM and setting its X1,X2,Y1,Y2 attributes manually rather than the constructor function.

```
gRight.append("line")
.attr("class","revenue-equilibrium-vertical-1")
.attr("stroke-dasharray",[5,5])
.style("stroke","yellow")
.attr("stroke-width",2)
```

The line is then dynamically set in terms of its X1 and X2 attributes by the user pressing a button. I need to get the Path string generated by D3 to feed into intersect.js which is an add on to calculate path intersections, but this library requires that I specify the relevant path string, What is the best way to go about obtaining this. Is there a getPath() method that access the SVG string?

```
  //need to get the SVG path string that is used to draw the line
  d3.select(".supply-equilibrium-vertical-1").attr("x1",equilibriumPositionSD.x).attr("x2",equilibriumPositionSD.x).attr("y1",equilibriumPositionSD.y).attr("y2",height)
```

Comment: You're mixing things in your question: are you talking about a `<line>` element or a `<path>` element?

Comment: I add a line but then I want to get the string Path representation of that line. Will I need to call a seperate d3.line and pass it the values to get a path representation is what I am asking or is there a D3 method for converting a line data to path.